# ChoiceMenu from hyperref and conditional statements

Tags: hyperref

Is it possible to lets say have 2 ChoiceMenu boxes and if a user choose one element in 'ChoiceMenu1' that will insert elements in 'ChoiceMenu2' depending on some criteria. My goal is to have one ChoiceMenu that have year 1980-2022, its like 42 elements. If I choose 1983 in 'ChoiceMenu1' i want the 'ChoiceMenu2' to show for exampleMovies released in 1983. Is this kind of functionallity possible?

ChoiceMenu1 ( a dropdown list ) is filled with elements (rows) range from 1980 - 2022, that means one element is 1980 and the next element is 1981 and so on. ChoiceMenu2 is empty from start and I want ChoiceMenu2 to be filled with elements that depends on my choice from ChoiceMenu1. Like this below

Look at the data below

-----------File of start ---------

1980, The Elephant Man;

1981, Atlantic City;

1980, Ordinary People;

----------End of file -------------

If I choose in 1980 in ChoiceMenu1 -> will fill ChoiceMenu2 with elements The Elephant Man (first element) and Ordinary People (second element).

Is this possible to have this kind of interaction with a pdf?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript can do that.

should be selfexplanining

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[pdftex]{insdljs}

\begin{insDLJS}[aeeae]{aeeae}{JavaScript auf Document Level}

function doStuff()
{
var Year1 =
  [
    ["Star Wars 4","a"],["Star Wars 5","b"],["Star Wars 6","c"]
  ];
var Year2 =
  [
    ["Star Wars 1","a"],["Star Wars 2","b"],["Star Wars 3","c"]
  ];

  if(this.getField("CMYear").value == "Year1")
  {
  this.getField("CMFilm").setItems(Year1);
  this.getField("CMFilm").currentValueIndices = 0;
  }
  else if(this.getField("CMYear").value == "Year2")
  {
    this.getField("CMFilm").setItems(Year2);
    this.getField("CMFilm").currentValueIndices = 0;   
    
  }
}
\end{insDLJS}

\begin{document}
\begin{Form}

\ChoiceMenu[name=CMYear,combo,calculate={doStuff()}]{Year:}{Year1,Year2}\\
\\
\ChoiceMenu[name=CMFilm,combo,calculate={doStuff()}]{Film:}{pls select Year}    

\end{Form}

\end{document}
```